# Merge multiple divs and then undo the merges

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

With the help of draggable and droppable from jquery-ui, I am able to drag the divs and merge their content, but, the client wants to have an undo/unjoin functionality as well. Example: if there are 3 divs named a, b and c, and the user merges b into a, and the c into (a+b), and then clicks the UNDO button, the user should get c and (a+b), and if the user clicks UNDO again, then a, b and c should be displayed as they were before any merge happened.

I am trying to do it with arrays so that I can store the different states of content that is merging:

```
var a = new Array(),
    b = new Array(),
    d = new Array(),
    c = new Array(),
    rel = new Array();
```

There are 4 arrays, 'b' holds the text from draggable div, 'a' holds the content of the droppable div that 'b' will merge with and get replaced in 'c', and 'd' holds the original content from 'a' so that an UNDO can happen. 'Rel' is the relation that is used in the undo functionality to refer to the merged divs by adding 'var[rel]' class, var 'i' is used to the same as well.

HTML:

```
<div class="document_content">
    <div class="row clause"> ... </div>
    <div class="row clause"> ... </div>
    <div class="row clause"> ... </div>
    <div class="row clause"> ... </div>
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$('.row.clause').droppable({
    accept: '.clause',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
    ...//code goes here for successful drop/merge
    }
 });

 $('.row.clause').draggable({
    revert: false,
    start: function (event, ui) {
        ui.helper.data('dropped', false);
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
 ...//code goes here for unsuccessful merge
    }
 });
```

The UNDO button has a counter which indicates how many times the div has been merged and or an UNDO can happen.

[Fiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/ck86ykhz/)

I apologise for the messy code, it is an early stage of development as of now.

Comment: Don't use `var a = new Array()`; instead, prefer the array literal: `var a = []`

Answer (score 1):

If I was you I would consider using a javascript framework such as angular or ember where you could elegantly store an objects history and then simply loop over all of them and revert them to their previous place.

But that isn't really what was asked.

So, if you're doing this with plain html and jquery and you only need to undo one step then I would consider storing the state on the elements themselves. Create a data-attribute on the moved elements (reset this on all elements) called something like data-previous-container and then when they click undo simply move the elements with a data-previous-container back to their previous containers. This will be much easier to debug and easier to understand than storing state in arrays. It can also handle adding more elements dynamically. If you need to be able to undo more than one turn, then you will need to store a history of states on each element and then work your way through each one for every time the user clicks undo.

Comment: I will try Angular as you suggested. It is an early stage of development so I can change/restart the code for this functionality.

Comment: Cool, angular is a great framework but be prepared to spend a couple of days getting familiar with the concepts and watching youtube talks if you havent used a frontend mvc framework before. Angular is a good choice though.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't done much Angular, but it seems not so complicated, I am looking at it now and will check into its details this weekend. I will post the solution here, if I am able to deduce any, that is.